# Not able to insert webpart in custom webpart zone in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, page-layout

I am able to add webpart zone snippet (from design manager) in my custom page layout. Although it gets added on the page layout.

But when I click on `add a webpart` in the `my custom webpart` zone section on the aspx page nothing happens.

[image: click here to view the webpart zone added]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can somebody please reply

Comment: is there any error message you are getting ? please check your console for that.

Comment: Also verify that your `WebPartAdder` section is not hidden.... Incase your custom CSS may override the default style mad may be responsible for hiding this section..